# How to set sigalarm to repeat over and over again in linux?

Tags: python, cygwin, signals, posix

I'm trying to make alarm work over and over again.

My handler is

```
def handler_SIGALRM(signum, frame):
    print "waiting"
    signal.alarm(2)
```

The alarm work only once, even though every time I set it again.
In my code I also use sigchld and sys.exit after the child working.

I'm running it with cygwin.

EDIT:
I need to write a code that will print "waiting" every second, with sigalarm and not loops

I'm an idiot, I edited the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

You put your `signal.alarm(2)` in a wrong place. See my example below.

```
import time
import signal

class TimeoutException (Exception):
    pass

def signalHandler (signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException ()

timeout_duration = 5

signal.signal (signal.SIGALRM, signalHandler)




for i in range (5):
    signal.alarm (timeout_duration)
    try:
        """Do something that has a possibility of taking a lot of time 
        and exceed the timeout_duration"""
        time.sleep (20)
    except TimeoutException as exc:
        print "Notify your program that the timeout_duration has passed"
    finally:
        #Clean out the alarm
        signal.alarm (0)
```

Comment: I need to use sigalarm (and not loops) to write "waiting" every second. I set it for the first time in the main.

Comment: Hi. I'm an idiot. My code didn't work because I edited another code